# String comparision in UTF8

Tags: java, string, utf-8

I have a PHP script which is supposed to return an UTF-8 encoded string. However, in Java I can't seem to compare it with it's internal string in any way.

If I print `"OK"` and response, they appear the same in console. However, if I check equality

`if ( "OK".equals(response) ) {`

the result is false. I printed out both in binary, response is `11101111 10111011 10111111 01001111 01001011`, the Java's String `"OK"` however is `01001111 01001011` which is cleary ASCII. I tried to convert it to UTF8 in a few ways, but no avail:

`String result2 = new String("OK".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

and

`String result2 = new String("OK".getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

are both not working, still return ASCII codes for some reason.

`byte[] result2 = "OK".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); System.out.print(new String(result2));`

While this also gives the correct `"OK"` result, in binary it still returns ASCII.

I've tried to change communication to numbers instead, but `1` still does not equal to `1`, as `Integer.parseInt(response)` returns `"1"` is not a String error message, altough in every other aspect, it is recognised as a normal String.

I'm looking for a solution preferably where `"OK"` is converted to UTF-8 and not response to ASCII, since I need to communicate with a PHP script along with 2 databases, all set to UTF-8. Java is started with the switch `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` to ensure national characters are not broken.

Comment: 01001111 01001011 is both ASCII and UTF-8. It's also the last two bytes of the PHP sequence. However, the PHP sequence additionally contains the three bytes EF BB BF. They are a byte order mark (BOM). BOMs have some value in UTF-16 and UCS-32. But in UTF-8 they are basically useless, a nuisance and the Unicode standard recommends against it. Get rid of it on the PHP side.

Comment: response.subtring(1) solved it perfectly!

Comment: @kry it is not a solution. It is a "workaround". Because it will make your script stop working, after you really have fixed the bug.

Comment: @AterLux I'm more afraid removing BOM from the start would actually break things. There is a lot of two way communication between databases, if I remove BOM I might need to check all communication functions all over the place. The files Java creates use BOM-less UTF-8, but I don't think anything in there is used for any interprogram communication.

Comment: @kry Please look at my updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in UTF-8 all characters with codes 127 or less are encoded by a single byte. Therefore `"OK"` in UTF-8 and ASCII is the same two bytes.

11101111 10111011 10111111 01001111 01001011 it is not just simple `"OK"` it is

`0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF, "OK"`

where `0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF` are a [BOM (Byte order mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

It is symbols which are not displayed by editors but used to determine the encoding.

Probably those symbols appeared in you php script before `<?php`

You have to configure your editor to remove BOM from the file

**UPD**

If it is not possible to alter the php script, you can use a workaround:

```
  // check if the first symbol of the response is BOM
  if (!response.isEmpty() && (response.charAt(0) == 0xFEFF)) {
    // removing the first symbol
    response = response.substring(1);
  }
```

Comment: response.charAt(1) runs to FALSE. I tried to recreate BOM in various ways, but they did not work either. response.substring(1) alone works as a workaround.

Comment: @kry It should be `charAt(0)` but honestly proper solution would be not sending BOM in the first place.

Comment: @kry sorry, my bad. It is charAt(0)